# Cannot boot from Thumbdrive

Tags: usb-drive

I created a bootable thumbdrive following the instructions and changed boot order of my laptop to USB first. My laptop still boots into Windows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: more detail about the instructions you followed would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop, I fixed it by finding the key on my laptop(esc in my case) that opened the boot menu(not the bios) during start up and then selecting to boot from the usb.

Hope it helps.